# Override Django's AuthenticationForm's fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

I am using Django's authentication backend and it works fine, but I want to give the username and password fields a custom CSS class. I have been trying to look for a solution but I cannot find anything here or anywhere else. This is what I have done so far:

project/forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg'}))
```

project/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .forms import LoginForm

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'), {'authentication_form': LoginForm}),
]
```

accounts/login.html:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.password }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

The login system works but I cannot get the CSS changes to show up. I inspected the username and password fields but they are not showing up in the browser at all. I am guessing I am missing something somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you can do it directly, but I use widget-tweaks to do that, and it works beautifully (also does all the error notification). You don't need to set anything in the form, everything is done in the template. The line in the template would then be:

```
    {% with "form-control input-field-"|add:form.username.name as field_class %}{% render_field form.username class=field_class %}{% endwith %}
```

That would give you a separate class for every input field. Have a look at https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it didn't work was because you were adding the {'authentication_form': LoginForm} with a path that has an include(....) in it, which is not possible, you needed to pass it only to the login url (or the ones where you are overriding that form for):

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view(authentication_form=LoginForm)),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Thank you, I have already used the suggestion made by @Paul Rene, but this is a good thing to know for someone to use for future reference. That's why I have fixed the code with working template for this case.